# Error: Bareword "params" not allowed while "strict subs"

Tags: perl, mod-perl

After clicking on a submit button, I am getting an error:

```
Bareword "params" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /var/www/path/get.pl line 71
```

Line 71:

```
my @names = params;
```

I do have `use strict;` nearly at the top.

How to fix?

Note: It work on the old server, I am moving all the files to a new server. Not sure where it went wrong?

Comment: Have you use'd the relevant web library (Dancer/CGI/whatever)? If so which

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`params` is most likely a name of a subroutine that was supposed to be imported from another module (based on style, *possibly* a constant which in Perl is implemented as a subroutine as well).

Search the rest of your code for both `sub params` and simply `my.*params` regexes on the old server, and make sure whichever file declares them is present on the new one..