# Bareword not allowed while "strict subs" in use

Tags: perl, material-design

I'm a researcher of high-barrier rubber materials. I meet some problems with the Perl by using the Materials Studo software. I can not understand what the Perl errors mean.

Here is the Perl script and its error

```
#!perl

use strict;

use Getopt::Long;
use MaterialsScript qw(:all);

for ( my $RxnRadius = my $MinRxnRadius; $RxnRadius <= my $MaxRxnRadius; $RxnRadius += 0.5 ) {

    my $xsdNameDist = sprintf( "%s_R%.2f", my $rootName, $RxnRadius );    #rename the new structure;

    if ( $RxnRadius > $MinRxnRadius ) {

        my $doc->Name = $xsdNameDist . "_init";
        ForciteGeomOpt( $doc, 20000 );                                    # run 20000 steps of Geometry Optimization

        my $results = ForciteDynamics( $doc, my $steps, "NPT" );
        $results->Trajectory->Delete;
    }

    for ( my $iteration = 1; $iteration <= my $IterationsPerRadius; $iteration++ ) {

        my $doc->Name = $xsdNameDist . "_" . $iteration;
        my $numBonds = createNewXlinks( $doc, $RxnRadius );
        my $reactedOligomerAtoms = 0;

        foreach my $atom ( @{ $doc->UnitCell->Atoms } ) {
            my $oligomerReactiveAtom;
            $reactedOligomerAtoms++ if ( $atom->Name =~ /^$oligomerReactiveAtom-\d/ );
        }

        my $conversion = 100 * my $totalOligomerAtoms;

        ( $reactedOligomerAtoms / $totalOligomerAtoms );

        if ( $numBonds == 0 ) {
            last;
        }

        optimizeAndPerturb( $doc );

        my $rowCounter;
        xlinkStatistics( $doc, $RxnRadius, $rowCounter );
        maxBondEnergy( $doc, $RxnRadius, $rowCounter ) if ( my $UseMaxBondEnergy );

        my $analysis_doc = Documents->New( "analyze.xsd" );
        $analysis_doc->CopyFrom( $doc );

        my $analyzeDuration;
        my $timeStep;

        my $steps   = ( $analyzeDuration * PICO_TO_FEMTO / $timeStep );
        my $freq    = int( $steps / 20 ); ### line 56
        my $results = Forcite Dynamics(
            $analysis_doc, $steps,
            "NPT",
            ( TrajectoryFrequency => $freq )
        );

        getTrajTempAndPressure( $results, $rowCounter, $RxnRadius );
        getEnergies( $results, $rowCounter );
        $analysis_doc->Delete;
        $results->Trajectory->Delete;

        if ( $conversion >= my $conversionTarget ) {

            my $numbondsDelete = my $xlinkCounter - $reactedOligomerAtoms - my $targetOligomerAtoms;

            if ( my $deleteExcessXlinks and $numbondsDelete > 0 ) {
                deleteExcessBonds( $doc, $numbondsDelete );
                xlink Statistics( $doc, "Final", $rowCounter );
            }
            else {
                my $textDoc->Append(
                    sprintf "There  are no excess bonds to delete\n "
                );
            }

            my $textDoc->Save;

            last;
        }

        Documents->SaveAll;
    }

    last if ( my $conversion >= my $conversionTarget );
}

my $doc->Name = my $rootName . "_final";
analyzeBonds( $doc );
XlinkSet( $doc );
Glasstransitiontemperature( $doc );
Documents->SaveAll;
```

Gives

> Bareword "PICO_TO_FEMTO" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at -e line 56.
>       -e had compilation errors.

I don't how to understand the notice or how to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).
An error on line 56 suggests that you've not done enough to minimize the code.  A bare word is an identifier with a sigil such as `$` (or `@` or `%` or …) in front of it.  You identify the line(s): ```my  $steps  =  ($analyzeDuration  * PICO_TO_FEMTO / $timeStep);  ***-----line 56***``` (it would be better to make the marker into a Perl comment), and `PICO_TO_FEMTO` does not have  `$` before it. Is `MaterialsScript` a public available module?

Comment: Occasionally, you can use barewords as constants: `use constant PICO_TO_FEMTO => 1.0E6;` for example (or is it `1.0E-6`? — it's only a factor of a trillion so you should be able to deduce which is correct). And then you might write `my $fm = PICO_TO_FEMTO * $pm;` to convert the picometres in `$pm` into the corresponding number of femtometres in `$fm`.

Comment: So you'd need a `use constant PICO_TO_FEMTO => 1E-03;`.  This can be given in the file you show or, rather, in the custom module that is `use`-ed, which is in the file `MaterialsScript.pm`.  If it is meant to be in that module, the `qw(:all)` indicates that it would be exported as needed.  So it is not clear from what you show why it's not there.  Or perhaps ... the constant is defined in some yet other module, which should be included but isn't?

Comment: The [constant](https://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html) is a pragma which defines constant subroutines so they may be used as "barewords," that is without a leading sigil (`$`, `@`, `%`) which Perl variables must have. Since in your case that apparently hasn't been done the interpreter complains about a bare-word.

Comment: I don't often work with units below pico (10⁻¹²) and thought femto was 10⁻¹⁸, but that's 'atto' and femto it is actually 10⁻¹⁵, so I was off by a factor of 1000 in converting between the two.  Ah well! (The Perl syntax was valid.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's not bad at all; I was probably off by 1e6. A million times!  And I still don't even know. (Can never be sure what is indented, but Factor "u1-to-u2" should mean u1 = F*u2, i guess.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Bareword "params" not allowed while "strict subs"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517270/error-bareword-params-not-allowed-while-strict-subs)

Comment: While this isn't exactly related, I just spent hours tracking down a similar issue.  It turned out to be a flippin spelling mistake.  Using `SENTINAL` threw an error, whereas the correct `SENTINEL` did not.  I mention it only because it might be a real error in some absurd cases.

Answer (score 3):

Probably some form of `PICO_TO_FEMTO` is imported from the `MaterialsScript` library you `use` at the beginning, as it's not defined in your script.

Have a look at the lib. My assumption is, its name is actually `$PICO_TO_FEMTO`, a simple scalar variable with a `$` sigil.

A bareword in Perl is an identifier without a sigil. If it's a function, it's OK. But this is probably a variable.

If you want to define a bareword variable, you do it like this:

```
use constant PICO_TO_FEMTO => 1000;
```

This creates a function called PICO_TO_FEMTO always returning 1000 under the hood.